# How to increase the performance of random get operation with huge(10million records) small(240Bytes in avg) record size in Hbase?

Tags: hbase, performance-testing, random-access

I have a Hbase table with four column families(totally 10 columns), the primary key is a fixed 10bytes id.The average row size is 240Bytes.

When I test the random get operation in HBase with 1 million rows, it gets 1000+rows/s, 0.25MB/s in average.

But when I test the same operation with 10million rows, it gets 160row/s, 0.04MB/s. After read some materials, I increased the HBASE_HEAPSIZE from 1G to 5G, after that I got 320rows/s, 0.08MB/s(cache hit raito is 87%), but it still much less than the speed in 1 million testsuite.

Does it has any methods to increase the performance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For random gets:

- decrease the block size, not more than 64kb, 32k should be good
- add a bloom filter on your table, at the row level
- split your table in multiple regions by setting a low region file max to 1Go or lower and presplit your table (by country, merchants, or whatever you want)
- activate the in memory
- use a fast compression codec (lzo or snappy are good)
- use a tablepool on your client side
- use memcache (...)

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful suggestions, I will try it now. It seems since 0.94 the tablepool of HBase is deprecate and it is said new HTable() with the same configuration will have the same effect compared to tablepool.